# Comparing 2 lists with nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have 2 CSV files (each of them have more than 1000 lines) like below:

**urls.csv**

```
https://github.com/spacewalkproject/spacewalk
https://github.com/troglobit/uftpd
https://github.com/danschultzer/pow
https://github.com/opencast/opencast
https://github.com/ipmitool/ipmitool
https://github.com/NetHack/NetHack
https://github.com/NetHack/NetHack
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
https://github.com/twitter/secure_headers
https://github.com/twitter/secure_headers
...
```

**2.csv**

```
JavaScript,46.70%,https://github.com/jsomara/katello
Ruby,57.50%,https://github.com/Katello/katello
Java,82.30%,https://github.com/candlepin/candlepin
PHP,86.10%,https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail
C,96.60%,https://github.com/torvalds/linux
JavaScript,82.60%,https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard
PHP,71.10%,https://github.com/nshahzad/phpVMS
Augeas,59.80%,https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas
null,null,https://github.com/horde/horde
JavaScript,88.00%,https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui
...
```

I want to include extra information from `2.csv` into `urls.csv` whenever urls matched in both files.

**My Code:**

```
import csv

with open('urls.csv') as f_input, open('2.csv') as f2_input, open('result.csv', 'w', newline="") as f_output:

    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_input2 = csv.reader(f2_input)

    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output,delimiter=",")

    for url in csv_input:
        for row in csv_input2:
            if(url[0]==row[2]):
                Language=row[0]
                Percentage=row[1]
                csv_output.writerow([url[0],Language,Percentage])
```

My code only produces this one line:

> https://github.com/spacewalkproject/spacewalk,Java,58.50%

**The problem:** this code just matches the first line of `urls.csv` against `2.csv` and then stops. I am sure there are more than 1000 of these urls that could be matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a dict from `csv_input2`, taking the url as key and the rest as value:

```
csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
csv_input2 = csv.reader(f2_input)

csv_output = csv.writer(f_output,delimiter=",")

data = {row[2]: (row[0], row[1] for row in csv_input2}

for url in csv_input:
    try:
        d = data[url[0]]
        csv_output.writerow([url[0],*d])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

I'm using try/except, because ask forgiveness not permission is faster. The rest should be self-explanatory

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the first time you go through `csv_input`, it reads the entire file, and reaches the end.  The second time through, there is nothing left to be read, so nothing is found.  The quick fix would be to move the `open('2.csv') as f2_input` into the outer for loop.

The issue with this approach is that you will be reading `csv_input2` once for every url in `csv_input1`, which is way slower than it needs to be.

A better way to approach this is to avoid the nested loop in the first place.  Have a first pass that adds all the urls into a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
urls = Set()
for url in csv_input:
   urls.add(url)
```

Now that you have all urls in memory, loop through the second CSV file, and check each row against all urls:

```
for row in csv_input2:
    url = row[2]
    if url in urls:
        Language=row[0]
        Percentage=row[1]
        csv_output.writerow([url,Language,Percentage])
```

Note, however, that this will not order the results by the order of the urls in the original file.  One possible way of doing that is to use a list rather than a set (to preserve order) and then having a sort phase after the for loop.

Comment: Nice solution with set, but it can change the order. The OP maybe don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

The csv file object is generator so when you iterate through the loop it reaches to end of the file. So next time there is no more item to iterate. So assign out of csv in list then perform operation.
**output_1= [url for url in csv_input]**
**output_2= [row for row in csv_input2]**

```
import csv

with open('urls.csv') as f_input, open('2.csv') as f2_input, open('result.csv', 'w', newline="") as f_output:

    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_input2 = csv.reader(f2_input)

    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output,delimiter=",")

    output_1= [url for url in csv_input]
    output_2= [row for row in csv_input2]

    for url in output_1:
        for row in output_2:
            if(url[0]==row[2]):
                Language=row[0]
                Percentage=row[1]
                csv_output.writerow([url[0],Language,Percentage])
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it stops is that you actually consume (i.e. read) all the second file in the inner loop and then in the second iteration (i.e second line of the first file) the inner loop does not actually run.

Two possible solutions - 
1. Use pandas and read the files as dataframe
2. Make sure you open and read the second file in the inner loop \ go back to the beginning of the file